# Change Odom topic name in Navigation stack

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, base-odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I have set up a simple navigation following the default configuration [from navigation tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup)
Right now, i am publishing odometry in the odom topic, and works fine, I can see the move_base subscribing to the odom topic. But i want to implement some filteres, so I am publising a filtered odometry message on a second topic name odom_filtered. what i want to know is how could I indicate the navigation stack to use the odom_filtered topic rather than the odom one?
Thanks for your time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360258/change-odom-topic-name-in-navigation-stack/) by [nalistic](https://answers.ros.org/users/55256/nalistic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2020-08-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2020-08-25**:
Need more details, what nodes of the navigation stack are you using? Most nodes are using the tf  odom->base_link, not the nav_msgs/Odometry topic. Make sure you are publishing this transform only in one node.

But if you really need to change a topic name for a node, try [remap](https://answers.ros.org/question/9248/how-do-you-remap-a-topic/)

**Comment by [nalistic](https://answers.ros.org/users/55256/nalistic/) on 2020-08-25**:
Thanks for your response, I am using move_base node, and that node was expecting the odometry to be published in the odom topic, so i could simply change the topic odom to odom_raw and use the remap property to change the odometry/filtered to odom, thanks a lot for the response, change the comment to an answer so i can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

using [remap](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap) as suggested by @humpelstizchen did the trick

---

Originally posted by [nalistic](https://answers.ros.org/users/55256/nalistic/) with karma: 15 on 2020-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0